# Sort array of JavaScript objects by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have an array of JavaScript objects. My array is defined like this:

```
var myObjects = [
  { id: '1', username: 'bill.jones', active: true, createdon: '03/29/2014' },
  { id: '2', username: 'woohoo', active: true, createdon: '03/28/2014' },
  { id: '3', username: 'someuser', active: true, createdon: '03/30/2014' }
];
```

This array is actually dynamically populated. Still, I need to sort the results by the createdon value in ascending order. To do that, I'm trying to use lodash. The createdon value represents a date. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
//  ORDER BY createdOn
myObjects.sort(function (a, b) {
  var date1 = new Date(a['createdon']);
  var date2 = new Date(b['createdon']);
  return date1 < date2;
});

_.forEach(myObjects, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Unfortunately, myObjects is still not sorted after I run this function. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: try `return date1 - date2;`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I just went through lodash doc, and perhaps you [could try `sortBy`](http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/3Wza8/

```
var myObjects = [
    { id: '1', username: 'bill.jones', active: true, createdon: new Date('03/29/2014') },
    { id: '2', username: 'woohoo', active: true, createdon: new Date('03/28/2014') },
    { id: '3', username: 'someuser', active: true, createdon: new Date('03/30/2014') }
];

myObjects = _.sortBy(myObjects, 'createdon');

_.forEach(myObjects, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

EDIT: as Cookie Monster pointed out, it's important that your `createdon` field is a Date, and not a string.

Comment: You're sorting by the string value, which can fail. http://jsfiddle.net/3Wza8/2/ You'll need to convert to dates first.

Comment: Well now you're changing the data structure. You should provide a solution that works for the actual situation presented.

Comment: I see your point, but given the question's context information, I think this is a potential solution for OP. Thanks though, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: It would work as a string if the dates are in a format like YYYYMMDD where a chronological sort = a string sort

Comment: For me, I needed `desc` order, so I used `_.orderBy(arrOfObjs, 'sort_key', 'desc')`. This method is pretty powerful, you should check out the docs on it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `sort` expects a function which returns -1, 0 or 1. Your function only returns 0 and 1.

This slight change should fix it:

```
myObjects.sort(function (a, b) {
  var date1 = new Date(a['createdon']);
  var date2 = new Date(b['createdon']);
  return date1 - date2;
});
```

Comment: Why not just `return date1 - date2;`?

Comment: I was under the assumption that sort expected -1, 0 or 1

Comment: It just requires negative/positive numbers or `0`. But the return results between the same two items should always be the same.

Comment: doesn't this need to be the `date1.getTime()` so you're comparing milliseconds since epoch?

Comment: @chovy `Date` coerces to `Number`. `+new Date()` is a common idiom as a shortcut to `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: `new Date() + 1000 //=>
"Sun Apr 02 2017 14:00:05 GMT-0700 (PDT)1000"` not what I would have expected.

Comment: Perhaps you know why that happens and you're stringing me along, but I'll bite. The `+` operator (by spec http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) first attempts to coerce to String, and then to Number. The `-` operator (spec http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.2) does not attempt to coerce to String. Which is why the code in my answer is just fine as-is.